# Access QSettings in my app

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I'm trying to implement application settings for my Qt app.
I'm working with `QSettings`, created an instance of my class like this

```
settings = new QSettings(qApp->organizationName(), qApp->applicationName());
```

and was wondering : **what is the best way to access my settings through my app**?

I will need access to some settings from different classes, but I don't know if I have to declare and create only one instance of QSettings and make it accessible everywhere I need it or if I can create local instances of `QSettings` where I need to access some of the settings.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a singletone, as the documentation of Qt says, [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html):

> If you use QSettings from many places in your application, you might want to specify the organization name and the application name using QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName() and QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(), and then use the default QSettings constructor:

Then, after the creation of the QApplication:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Set up, the different default parameters:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("MySoft");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("mysoft.com");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Star Runner");
```

When, you want to use QSettingsm just use the default constructor that will takes the default parameters from the core application:

```
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("example", 68);
```

Under QML, the alternative is [Settings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html), the setps are the same, configure your gui app:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setOrganizationName("Some Company");
app.setOrganizationDomain("somecompany.com");
app.setApplicationName("Amazing Application");
```

And in QML, set up the different settings:

```
Settings {
   property alias x: window.x
   property alias y: window.y
   property alias width: window.width
   property alias height: window.height
}
```

Comment: So as long as I create local instances with the constructor specifying the organization name and application it's ok ?

Comment: @nmud Once QCoreApplication is setup (typically in your main function), then you only need to use the parameter-less constructor for QSettings wherever you need settings.

Comment: The problem would be if qsettings uses custom format

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to do that is implement Singleton design pattern to allocate QSettings object but keeping in mind that if you share QSettings you have to deal with that the atomic persistence, I mean, you will need to use sometimes sync() method in order to persist some data across your C++ classes. I understand that you don't need to use Settings in QML layer. If it is the case, you can look **[qmlRegisterSingletonType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType)** method in order to use that in QML.

Comment: But do I need singleton design if I'm creating a unique instance of QSettings in the constructor of my main window ? I just need the preferences to be taken into account the next time the app is launched, so I probably do not need to call sync() either ?

Comment: @jgd yes , that's best choice to access a global settings with a singleton class +1

Comment: @nmud sync() is called just after persist. Do you need write or just read settings?

Comment: @jgd I need to write settings from one location and read settings from multiple locations in my code

Comment: @nmud Good, my advice is use sync() when you write in spite of QSettings have cached memory to use, so when you read in one location, the settings will be consistent but if your app crash in the middle of execution, could be inconsistent in the next execution. Also, as I have said, use a singleton design for this object.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a global setting in your whole application `singleton` could be a nice idea, i have a pattern for settings class and i post here maybe useful to you and others.

Here i have `GlobalSettings` class which is a singleton following is header and cpp files.

header file :

```
#ifndef GLOBALSETTINGS_H
#define GLOBALSETTINGS_H

#include <QSettings>
#include <QObject>

class GlobalSettings
{
public:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(GlobalSettings)

    static GlobalSettings* getSettings();

    // Settings getter and setters

    QString Setting1() const;
    void setSetting1(const QString &Setting1);

    QString Setting2() const;
    void setSetting2(const QString &Setting2);

private:

    // private constructor
    GlobalSettings();
    static GlobalSettings * m_Settings;

    QSettings * settings;

    // Settings memebers
    QString m_Setting1;
    QString m_Setting2;

};

#endif // GLOBALSETTINGS_H
```

and the cpp file for GlobalSettings

```
#include "globalsettings.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>

GlobalSettings * GlobalSettings::m_Settings = NULL;

GlobalSettings::GlobalSettings()
{
    settings = new QSettings(qApp->organizationName(), qApp->applicationName());
    if (!settings->contains("Setting1"))
    {
        settings->setValue("Setting1","Something"); //  default value
    }
    else
    {
        m_Setting1 = settings->value("Setting1").toString();
    }

    if (!settings->contains("Setting2"))
    {
        settings->setValue("Setting2","Something"); //  default value
    }
    else
    {
        m_Setting2 = settings->value("Setting2").toString();
    }
    settings->sync();
}

GlobalSettings *GlobalSettings::getSettings()
{
    if (m_Settings == NULL)
    {
        m_Settings =  new GlobalSettings();
    }
    return m_Settings;
}

QString GlobalSettings::Setting1() const
{
    return m_Setting1;
}

void GlobalSettings::setSetting1(const QString &Setting1)
{
    m_Setting1 = Setting1;
    settings->setValue("Setting1",Setting1);
}

QString GlobalSettings::Setting2() const
{
    return m_Setting2;
}

void GlobalSettings::setSetting2(const QString &Setting2)
{
    m_Setting2 = Setting2;
    settings->setValue("Setting2",Setting2);
}
```

and here is how to use it where ever you want to use

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDebug>

#include <globalsettings.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    GlobalSettings * setting = GlobalSettings::getSettings();

    qDebug() <<  setting->Setting1();


    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and now if you want to have thread safe settings class you may lock a mutex at get and setter functions

Comment: Is it essential to have a global variable for this ? I'm not very comfortable with global variables and if working with local instances works I'd rather go for that.

Comment: Will do. Also, isn't QSettings thread safe ? Why do I need mutex if it's the case ?